# regex greedy match ends with character or end of string

Tags: python, regex, regex-greedy

I have two strings:

1) "Created Account Owner Sharing Rule test1"

2) "Updated Account Owner Sharing Rule test3: Changed CaseAccessLevel from Read/Write to Read Only"

As result of regex matching I want to see:

1) Created Account Owner Sharing Rule test1

2) Updated Account Owner Sharing Rule test3

divided into 4 groups:

1) (Created) (Account) (Owner Sharing Rule) (test1)

2) (Updated) (Account) (Owner Sharing Rule) (test3)

For this purposes I tried use the next python regex:

```py
'^(?P<action>^[^\s]+)\s(?P<target_object_label>.+)\s(?P<object_type>Owner\sSharing\sRule)\s(?P<object_label>.+)(?=:|$)
```

but for the second string 4th group looks like 'test3: Changed CaseAccessLevel from Read/Write to Read Only'.

Essentially regex should stop either in the end of line or before ':' character but greedy match doesn't allow to do this.

Thanks in advance for the answers,

Dzmitry

Comment: Something like this: **https://regex101.com/r/sU5dD2/1** ?

Comment: Following any quantifier with a `?` means a "minimal match", for example `.+?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ***could*** do:

```
^(?P<action>\S+)\ 
(?P<target_object_label>.+)\s
(?P<object_type>Owner\ Sharing\ Rule)\s
(?P<object_label>[^:\n]+)               # stop before : or newline
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/sU5dD2/1) (mind the different modifiers!).

Comment: Thanks Jan! This is exactly what I need!

Comment: @Dzmitry: Glad to help.